# What are conditions for an infinite sum with a complex parameter not to be analyitically extendable?

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, exponential-function, analyticity, statistical-mechanics

I'm looking for a sequence $f(n)$, so that

$g(z):=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N\exp\left(-z\cdot f(n)\right),$

with $z$ so that this converges classically, defines a function which can not be analytically continued, i.e. the sum is as good as it gets.

For a non-example, plugging using $f(n)=n$ leads, for $z>0$ and ${\mathrm{e}}^{-z}<1$, to $\frac{1}{1-{\mathrm{e}}^{-z}}$, but this can be extended to make sense for $z=-9001$. Plugging in $f(n)=\log(n)$ leads to the zeta function. All examples where I'm able to compute the sum for some $z$ lead to something extendable.

PS: It would also be great if the result is ${\mathcal C}^\infty$.

Comment: Any strictly increasing non-negative integer sequence which satisfies:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} = \infty$$
will work. It give you a function which cannot analytic continue to the left half plane ($\Im z < 0$). 
e.g, $f(n) = n^2$. This is a consequence of
[Fabry gap theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabry_gap_theorem).

In fact, every strictly increasing non-negative integer sequence whose gap $\Delta_n = f(n+1) - f(n)$ is not ultimately periodic will work. That will be a consequence of Polya-Carlson theorem. Unfortunately, I can't find a reference for what that is online.

Comment: @achillehui: Thanks for the responds. Okay, it seems the Fabry theorem is actually formulated for $z^{f(n)}$ instead of ${\mathrm e}^{-z\,f(n)}$ so one has to reformulate it a bit. In any case, do you know any "function with a known name" which fits?

Comment: The first one come to my mind is [Jacobi theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function):

$$\vartheta(\omega;\tau) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \exp( \pi i n^2\tau + 2\pi i n \omega)$$

and you set $\omega = 0$ and $z = -\pi i \tau$.